# Parsing a large text file in Python

Tags: python, regex, file, text

I am trying to parse a large text file (~ 20,000 lines) in Python.  It is an exam so the format for each block of text begins like the following:

(3.1.1.1) The first question contains several lines.

(3.1.1.2) The next question contains more lines.

I am trying to split the text by matching on the pattern (3.1.* with a regex with the following code:

```
for line in data(0,10):    #start with the first 10 lines to check it
results = re.match("^(3.1.*", line)
if len(results.group()) != 0:
  print line
```

I can handle the rest once I get it split (transfer it to a dictionary, etc.) But I need some help getting started on the splitting it out based on the pattern.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following expression:

```
^\(3\.1\..*?(?=\(\d+\.\d+\.|\Z)
```

Matches from "`(3.1.`" until right before the next:

- `\(\d+\.\d+\.` begging of another question, or
- `\Z` the end of file

You need to set the following flags:

```
re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
```

Test online [here](https://regex101.com/r/kF6eQ8/1)

The key to this solution lies in using `.*?`, a [lazy quantifier (the extra **?**)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) -check that link. Basically, it tries to match as less as it can.

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the string into question number and question value. Then, iterate over the list and set into a dictionary.

```
import re

data = """(3.1.1.1) The first question contains several lines.

(3.1.1.2) The next question contains more lines."""

splitted = re.split('\(([\d\.]*)\)',data)

paired = {}
# splitted contains an empty string on the 0th index
for i in range(1, len(splitted) - 1, 2):
    paired[splitted[i]] = splitted[i+1]
```

Comment: Maybe, it should try to avoid parens inside questions, ie `(3.1.1.1) The first question contains several (too many) lines`

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a list (`parsed`) of a list of question blocks, splitting the blocks on occurrence of the question number pattern:

```
import re
import pprint

parsed = []
lastblock = []
newblockregex = re.compile('^\(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\).*')
with open('data.txt') as exam:
    for line in exam.readlines():
        if newblockregex.match(line.rstrip('\n')):
            if lastblock:
                parsed.append(lastblock)
                lastblock = []
            lastblock = [line.rstrip('\n')]
        else:
            lastblock.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
parsed.append(lastblock)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(parsed)
```

Example data:

```
(splitexam)macbook:splitexam joeyoung$ cat data.txt
(3.1.1.1) The first question contains several lines.
line1 words1
line2 words
line3 words

(3.1.1.2) The next question contains more lines.
line1 words2
line2 words
line3 words

(3.1.1.3) The next question contains more lines.
line1 words3
line2 words
line3 words
```

Output:

```
[   [   '(3.1.1.1) The first question contains several lines.',
        'line1 words1',
        'line2 words',
        'line3 words',
        ''],
    [   '(3.1.1.2) The next question contains more lines.',
        'line1 words2',
        'line2 words',
        'line3 words',
        ''],
    [   '(3.1.1.3) The next question contains more lines.',
        'line1 words3',
        'line2 words',
        'line3 words',
        '']]
```